# How to change the URL and template page after login?

Tags: ajax, templates, jsf, facelets, icefaces

I am working on a JSF and Hibernate web app with ICEfaces. I am using two Facelets templates, one for the login page and one for the rest of the site.

The problem is, when I click on the login button, it goes to the home page, but without changing the URL nor the template. When I enter the right URL, it goes to it and displays the right template.

I know that ICEfaces uses Ajax and partially updates the page, but I want to know how to stop that, I want it to load the entire requested page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send a redirect after login. You can achieve this by appending a `faces-redirect=true` request parameter to the navigation outcome.

```
public String login() {
    // ...

    return "home?faces-redirect-true";
}
```

Or if you're still using the ancient JSF 1.x with `<navigation-case>`s in `faces-config.xml`, then you can achieve the same by adding a `<redirect />` to the `<navigation-case>` in question.

```
<naviagation-case>
    <from-outcome>home</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/home.jsf</to-view-id>
    <redirect />
</navigation-case>
```

Comment: Which JSF and ICEfaces version exactly are you using?

Comment: that is what i do                                             public String validateUser() throws Exception {
String page="";
if (help.getUser(username, password).isEmpty()) { 
setInvalidMessage("Invalid User Name Or Password");
page = "index.xhtml";
} else {

Comment: if (userdata.getUserstype().getTypeId() == 1) {
setSideNav("/WEB-INF/template/sections/author/side-nav.xhtml");
setBarStatus("v");
setCourNav("/WEB-INF/template/sections/author/course-sidenav.xhtml");
page = "profileAU.xhtml?faces-redirect-true";}

Comment: else if (userdata.getUserstype().getTypeId() == 2) {
                setSideNav("/WEB-INF/template/sections/side-nav.xhtml");
                setBarStatus("display: none");
                setCourNav("/WEB-INF/template/sections/course-sidenav.xhtml");
                page = "profileST.xhtml?faces-redirect-true";
            }

Comment: else {
                page = "admin.xhtml?faces-redirect-true";
            }
        }
        return page;
    }

Comment: i am  using jsf 2.0 icefaces 2.0.2

Comment: Are you using `<ice:form>`? Try a normal `<h:form>`.

Comment: i am using <h:form> all tags used jsf tags problem happend after just add icefaces framework to jsf project